# Is topological sort of an original graph same as dfs of the transpose graph

Tags: graph, topological-sort

I have an intuition that topo-sort of an original graph
is the same as dfs of the transpose graph (reverse all the edges)

```
 A -> B -> C
 D -> B
```

topo-sort is  [D, A, B, C]   or  [A, D, B, C]

If I transpose the graph (reverse all the edges)

```
  C -> B -> A   
       B -> D
```

the dfs also gives  [D, A, B, C]   or  [A, D, B, C]

Please, I can't mathematically prove/ disprove it. 
If the proposition is incorrect, an counter example would helpful

Comment: Consider (cross-)posting this on [Computer Science.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/). They're better equipped for answering theoretical CS questions. SO tends to be more practical.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/124725/is-topological-sort-of-an-original-graph-same-as-dfs-of-the-transpose-graph

Comment: To be more clear, in "dfs of the transpose graph", it might be better to say "post-order of dfs" instead of "dfs".

Answer (score 1):

This isn’t a coincidence - you’ve just rediscovered a common algorithm for finding topological orderings!

One algorithm that’s commonly used to find topological orderings works by doing a DFS and writing out the nodes in the reverse order of their finishing times. (Try it!) Your algorithm is essentially equivalent to this.

Other algorithms - like Kosaraju’s algorithm for computing strongly connected components - make use of similar insights.